# WP 3.5 caching problem

Tags: cache

Ok so ever since I upgraded some of my sites to WP 3.5 recently, it looks like caching of specifically images and css files are screwed. To explain:

If I try to update an image, it keeps on showing the old version of the image even after clearing my browser cache. I'm on a Mac, and tried FF and Chrome and cleared cache for both of them, delivering same results. If I add a parameter to the image URL (to bust the cache) it loads the new image, but then if I remove the parameter it reverts back to the old version again. I did notive that cmd+shift+R does some kind of a refresh that forces the new images/changes to display, but any subsequent "normal" refreshes reverts back again.

Same thing happens with my CSS files as explained above for images.

I even installed and tried W3TC to add expires headers to my assets and do the caching there, but that didn't really fix anything.

Can anyone maybe just point me in the right direction to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WordPress does nothign to re-write your image urls, it just sticks them in. Requests for images, CSS, JS, files go directly to your web server. Your server has some agressive caching. Or, if you're using a CDN, the CDN won't "pull" new version unless you invalidate the old version. In short: probably not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Are you "updating the image" through the dashboard or through the file-system (FTP, SSH, etc)?

Comment: I'm using FTP. Thanks for the replies. I can't seem to see any caching happening on the server though.

Comment: Ok I downgraded back to Wordpress 3.4.2 and now everything works perfectly. This is definitely a WP 3.5 issue then. Does anyone know what changes have been made in terms of asset caching from WP 3.4.2 - 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this but I found out in the end that my ISP was doing some kind of caching on their end. Had to phone them and explain the issue. When they started seeing it too, I kwen the problem was with them.

Thanks for all the comments btw.